# Objective-C Block type as return value

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

How do I write the following:

```
typedef void (^T)(void);
T f() {
    return ^{};
}
```

without the typedef?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
void (^f())(void) { 
  return ^{};
}
```

You'd better keep the typedef as the return type is not easy to understand in this form.

Comment: What's the rationale for this strangeness? The function parameters are inside the return type?