# Return Objective-C block from C function

Tags: objective-c, block

What is the syntax to declare a C function that returns an Objective-C block? Is it possible?

I thought it should be something like

```
(void (^)(void)) myFunctionReturningABlock();
```

but that won't compile.

Comment: When you say doesn't work, could you elaborate a little? Does it break at runtime or does it generate a compiler error or warning? Let us know what "doesn't work" means and we can help you further.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Block type as return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948173/objective-c-block-type-as-return-value)

Comment: @Jasarien Sorry, I'm getting lazy. Fixed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The syntax for your function is slightly incorrect.

As I understand it, you should define your block as a type which you can use as the return type for your function like this:

```
typedef void(^MyAwesomeBlock)(void);

MyAwesomeBlock blockFunction()
{
    MyAwesomeBlock block = ^{
        //some code;
    };

    return block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I also tried the 'typedef-less' version in the linked possible duplicate, but having a typedef makes it so much clearer.

Comment: Is there a typedef-less version of this?

Comment: @nielsbot if you read the comment just above yours, you'll notice that Nick refers to a typedef-less linked in a comment on the question, further up the page. But as Nick says, using a typedef makes the code much more readable - you generally don't want a typedef-less version, unless you want messy unreadable code?? :/

Comment: oh.. I looked for it here... I see it's in an answer to a question linked to via a comment on this question ;-)